# TS do not show error if payload Partitial

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Why is there no error if I make payload Partial? I can see that TS checks only first value, but not second one.

```
type UserState = {
  user: User | null;
  loading: boolean;
  error: Error | null
}

type UserAction = {
  type: typeof SET_USER;
  payload: Partial<UserState>;
};

 type ActionUser = SetDetailedUserAction;


const fetchUser =
  (
    id: string,
  ): ThunkAction<
    Promise<Any>,
    RootState,
    any,
    ActionUser
  > =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    
dispatch({
      type: SET_USER,
      payload: { loading: true, ffff: false }, /// no error for `ffff`
    });
}
```

Usual TS show the error in this case, and I could not find any problems in Redux ThunkAction types. Maybe anyone saw similar comments problem?

Answer (score 0):

~~I don't see your `dispatch` being typed in any way to only accept specific actions - so it probably just accepts everything.~~ (Ah, saw it. That's just not a common pattern any more, so I missed that)

TypeScript is Duck-Typed.
You want to dispatch something that has matches the shape of `UserAction` - so it has **at least** those properties. TypeScript is perfectly fine with you adding additional properties on top. In some edge cases, it will complain, but generally it will just be okay with it.

---

That said, you probably shouldn't do any of this - this is an extremely outdated style of Redux and nowadays you would not do something like writing action types by hand. Modern Redux (official recommendation since 2019) is about 1/4 of the code.

Please read [Why Redux Toolkit is How To Use Redux Today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) and follow [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)